# PySceneDetect FFmpeg Not Available

Tags: python, macos, ffmpeg

I already installed FFmpeg and this is available in terminal I can convert video and etc, but it's completely not available in PySceneDetect.

pip installed FFmpeg-python and FFmpeg library and FFmpeg itself in system.

PySceneDetect returns:

```
ffmpeg could not be found on the system. Please install ffmpeg to enable video output support.
```

I think trouble with path, but can't put path in PySceneDetect. I can use path to binary FFmpeg, only in ffmpeg-python library, like this and it's working

This code working fine:

Here i using only FFmpeg-python library

```
stream = ffmpeg.input('vi0.mp4')
stream = ffmpeg.filter(stream, 'fps', fps=10, round='up')
stream = ffmpeg.output(stream, 'vi1.mp4')
ffmpeg.run(stream,cmd='./ffmpeg')
```

But can't it to get work with PySceneDetect

```
print(scenedetect.video_splitter.is_ffmpeg_available())
```

return False

```
split_video_ffmpeg(video_path, scene_list, show_progress=False)
```

returns "ffmpeg could not be found on the system. Please install ffmpeg to enable video output support."

Comment: So you say ffmpeg itself is installed on the system; that means you can run it by just typing `ffmpeg` right into a command prompt, right? If not, then it's either not installed, or not in your system PATH.

Comment: right. I can use FFmpeg in command prompt

Comment: The error could be a red herring. According to [the code](https://github.com/Breakthrough/PySceneDetect/blob/93aed414c5a33add079dbba54bdaf2595ea5b431/scenedetect/video_splitter.py#L291), that error happens whenever an OSError is caught. So, you'd have to modify and step through their code to actually see what that OSError is, I think. Also keep in mind there's an [issues page}(https://github.com/Breakthrough/PySceneDetect/issues) on their GitHub, so ask there if you can't get any help from here.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I installed PyScene **prior** to ffmpeg.
It did not work in PyCharm
As a matter of fact I installed the package (PyScene + ffmpeg) for windows, but it refused to find it again.
So I opened the project with VS Code, and that works fine
..
Honestly I do not have the explanation .. maybe something is cached.
You can try the same.